# For loop continue why is the resulting number 16?

Tags: javascript

Im starting to learn programming, and there is a particular part of the course that is blowing over my head, in the continue section about for loops, im asked to write the output of this code:

```js
var sum=0;
for(i=4; i<8; i++) {
if (i == 6) {
continue;
}
sum += i;
}
document.write(sum);
```

and for whatever reason, it is supposed to equal 16, i just cant quite picture in my head why, thank you in advance!

Comment: Your best bet here is to follow it through step-by-step in the debugger, and/or work it out on paper. (Using a debugger is not an advanced skill, it's basically the next thing a student should learn after "Hello, World".)

Comment: 4+5+7 = 16 for the value 6, it just skips the function after that and proceeds with the iteration

Comment: You should use console.log for debug purposes, and see what's your doing step-by-step

Comment: @MiguelCruz - No, he/she should use the debugger for debug purposes. No sense stumbling around in the dark with a `console.log` torch when you an *turn on the lights* with the debugger.

Comment: Please, when asking a question, take a minute or two to indent your code. It makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's follow it through:

1. `sum = 0`
2. At the beginning of the loop, `i = 4`.
3. `i < 8` is true so the loop continues (yes, this check happens at the very beginning)
4. Since `i == 6` is false, `continue` doesn't happen
5. `sum += i` sets `sum` to `4`
6. `i++` sets `i` to `5`;
7. `i < 8` is true so the loop continues
8. `i == 6` is false so `continue` doesn't happen
9. `sum += i` sets `sum` to `9`
10. `i++` sets `i` to `6`
11. `i < 8` is true so the loop continues
12. Since `i == 6` is true, `continue` moves on to the next loop iteration, skipping the rest of the loop body
13. `i++` sets `i` to `7`
14. `i == 6` is false so `continue` doesn't happen
15. `sum += i` sets `sum` to `16`
16. `i++` sets `i` to `8`
17. `i < 8` is false so the loop stops

Step #12 is probably the most interesting step: `continue` skips the rest of the loop body, moving on to the next loop iteration. More about `continue` [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue).

Put it another way: The loop sets `i` to `4`, increments `i` once per loop, and continues while `i < 8`. That means that within the loop body, `i` will be `4`, then `5`, then `6`, then `7`. In the loop body, `sum += i` adds `i` to `sum` *except* when `i == 6` because `continue` skips over that part. So `sum += i` happens for `4`, `5`, and `7`. Since `sum` starts at `0`, it's `0 + 4 + 5 + 7` which is `16`.

Comment: To make it simple: the code doesn't print the value of `i`, but the sum of the values of `i` from 4 to 7, except 6.

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens in following loop

1. initially `sum` is `0`
2. after first loop `i(4)` is added to `sum`
3. in second loop `i(5)` is added so `sum` become `9`
4. in third loop nothing is added to `sum` because  `i=6` so `continue` statement will be executed before adding `i` to `sum`
5. last last loop `i(7)` is added to sum and result becomes `16`.
6. as condition for loop is `i<8` so last value added be `7`